# How to get Controller Name and its properties in another class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing a MVC application.
I want to send a controller for validating purpose to Validation class.
That class will validate the controllers properties and send the result.
I am not gettting, how to get name and properties of the controller after 
getting it in class.

Below code is the Controller class code and I send this controller to class named validation class.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)

    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Validations v = new Validations();
            Boolean ValidProperties = true;

            //Sends the controller to Validation class
            v.ValidProperty(this);



             if (ValidProperties == true)
             {
                 db.Locations.Add(location);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");

             }


        }
     }
```

And Below code is the class named Validations where I want to validate the controller .

Now I am not getting how to get the name of controller and its properties.

```
  public class Validations
{
   string PropertName;




    public void  ValidProperty(Controller ctr)
    {

        var name1 = ctr;


        string s = ctr. ????????
        //How to get Controller Name and its properties ? 


    }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want your validator to know anything about your controller?

Comment: Its a requirement...some custom validations.

Comment: Requirement is something coming from customer side; how you implement it is entirely up to you. Still, *why* do you need this, why have you designed it so and what "properties" of controller you need to "validate"?

Comment: I will tell the situation, In above Code I used Location controller, In this case,  I need to validate location name with min 10 characters long and max 50 charterers. I want to handle this situation. so I want to validate the controller, same for other modules as well.

Comment: `Location` is viewmodel, so you need to validate your viewmodel and not your controller. Any BTW this is done as simply as placing `[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10)]` attribute on `Name` property.

Comment: well, I cant put validations on class properties, because my model and database is not stable/freeze yet and if I generate the class from the model then all the validations could be lost.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use ViewModel in above scenario ?

Comment: Even if you can't put validations on class properties, you still don't need controller for your validation, only viewmodel. And regarding "how to use" - I don't understand your question, you are already using viewmodel (it's your `Location location`), you just have to pass it to validator and validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use reflection to get name as:

```
var name = this.GetType().Name;
```

Or you can create a custom base controller of your choice, add properties, methods to it and deal with  derived controllers as:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    // add other properties as needed
    public abstract string Name { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void ValidProperty()
    {
        string s = Name;
        //something esle
    }

}

public class YourController : BaseController
{
    private string _name;
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        protected set { _name = "Your_Name"; }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            bool validProperties = true;

            // Deals with a base controller method
            ValidProperty();

            // or something like this, if you prefer

            var controller = (BaseController) this;
            Validations v = new Validations();
            //Sends the controller to Validation class
            v.ValidProperty(controller);


            if (validProperties)
            {
                db.Locations.Add(location);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
        }
        return Content(string.Empty);
    }       
}
```